# What type of adapter should be used in this case? Singleton or shared preferences method?

Tags: java, android, singleton, sharedpreferences, adapter

I am developing android application. I did not plan my project that much before. So when I thought that I finished my task then I realized that I am not done at all. I have some issues that I figured it out now. I want to go again from the beginning of the project.

I want to get the list of **training** that is in external database and data will be populated manually using SQLite browser (only training table, columns are _id, title, description, date and time, location.). And onclick of that item in list, it should start new activity with holding the training session all along the application activity. [On Training, people will fill their personal information (Now, person table), where the data of person should be stored in the particular training session].

Now, my questions are;
 1. What type of Adapter should I use in this case and why? 
 2. Should I use shared preferences or Singleton method to keep the session of **training** all activities of application?

Answer (score 0):

Both of those question are determined by your requirements for this software.  You said it yourself that you 'did not plan my project that much before'.  Sounds like you're at a point where you need to do some hard thinking about your requirements.  Requirements will, in turn, determine the technologies/ methodologies you need to use.

With the information you've provided, it would be impossible for anyone to provide advice that would be anything better than a guess.

Comment: You misunderstood my sense of humor dude @claymore 1977. I almost finished my project. What I realized now is the training session. I was thinking that with query I could have connection between the tables in database but it seemed impossible now. After researching I realized the technology Singleton and shared preferences. 
So, before I start to do something, I am just trying to find the developers view here. That's it.